# Receiving and returning Reactive Types apache kafka with micronaut 2.1.3

Tags: java, apache-kafka, rx-java2, micronaut, micronaut-kafka

I am using Micronaut application for Receiving and returning Reactive Types with apache Kafka. From the Micronaut documentation https://micronaut-projects.github.io/micronaut-kafka/latest/guide/

There is a method for Receiving and returning Reactive Types as below

This method is in the consumer(Listener side)

```
@Topic("reactive-products")
public Single<Product> receive(
        @KafkaKey String brand,  
        Single<Product> productFlowable) { 
    return productFlowable.doOnSuccess((product) ->
            System.out.println("Got Product - " + product.getName() + " by " + brand) 
    );
}
```

Is there any example of consuming this method, how the return value will be processed in the Producer side?

Answer (score 0):

In this example, when returning a reactive type, Micronaut framework creates the subscription to the `Single<Product>`.

You would not write any code to "consume" the above method, since that is handled by the framework.  The code above is a kafka consumer implementation, and will receive `Product` instances when consumer records are fetched from the kafka broker for the configured `@Topic`.

For producing messages, you can refer to here: https://micronaut-projects.github.io/micronaut-kafka/latest/guide/#kafkaClient.